# Difference between Vlookup() and Match()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I want to perform a search on column 2 to find keywords that are missing in Column 1. I used the `formula =IF(MATCH(G2,$E$2:$E$117,0),1,"No")` so for rows that return 1, it means that the keyword exists in column 1. When a keyword in Column 2 cannot be found in Column 1, my formula will return #N/A. (Image attached)

However, I would like to understand whether this can be done in a much simpler way, perhaps using **vlookup function**? If so, how?

I am also unsure about the **difference** between this formula and the vlookup.

Hope someone experienced with Excel functions could explain it to me. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH returns the relative location of the value in the range, while VLOOKUP will return the value.

When using MATCH wrap it in ISNUMBER to deal with the fact that if not found the MATCH will return an Error:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G2,$E$2:$E$117,0)),1,"No")
```

Now instead of an error you will get `No` in the field when not found.

---

Another method would be to use COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$117,G2),1,"No")
```

Although shorter, it will be slower than the MATCH version.  It may not be noticeable with the limited data set but too many(10,000+) will cause problems.

---

To use VLOOKUP:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(G2,$E$2:$E$117,1,FALSE)),"No",1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the guidance! May I ask if using vlookup is possible to solve this question too?

Comment: @Rosellx yes, but Match for this type of thing is quicker. See edit.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for clarifying. Appreciate it a lot! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the perfect occasion to try the **Brand NEW**

> XLOOKUP (wooo)

XLOOKUP is different from VLOOKUP in that it uses separate lookup and return arrays, where VLOOKUP uses a single table array followed by a column index number.

### Syntax

```
=XLOOKUP (lookup, lookup_array, return_array, [not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])
```

### Arguments

lookup - The lookup value.

lookup_array - The array or range to search.

return_array - The array or range to return.

not_found - [optional] Value to return if no match found.

match_mode - [optional] 0 = exact match (default), -1 = exact match or next smallest, 1 = exact match or next larger, 2 = wildcard match.

search_mode - [optional] 1 = search from first (default), -1 = search from last, 2 = binary search ascending, -2 = binary search descending.

Comment: Yes, but Xlookup will not return `1` if found, it can be set to return `No` if not found, but like Vlookup it will return the value if found.  so one would have to still use `IF(Xlookup(...)={not_found_value},1,"No")`

Comment: Don't forget there is also `XMATCH`